# Can I use Hibernate OGM with Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, hibernate-ogm

Can I use Hibernate OGM with Cassandra? Is it appropriate? or are there any alternatives to it? What is the better project architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate OGM supports Cassandra: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.2/reference/en-US/html/ch14.html